# Django Form With Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I've made a model with foreign keys in order to save some typing, and I think it also looks cleaner this way:

```
class Model_Sub( models.Model ):
    some_fields

class Model_Main( models.Model ):
    field_1 = models.ForeignKey( Model_Sub, related_name="sub_field_1" )
    field_2 = models.ForeignKey( Model_Sub, related_name="sub_field_2" )
```

But when I want my users to submit the form, I want new instances of the sub model, not from a query set. I want the Model_Sub to be seamlessly included with the main model as a form. Is there anyway to achieve this using ModelForm?

Thanks for the help

David

Comment: Is `Model_Sum` a summing function, or are you referring to `Model_Sub`?

Comment: sorry, I was referring to Model_Sub. Fixed it.

Comment: So you want a form which can save its values to a new foreign-keyed instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use two models forms from your `Model_Sub` class then use them to create your `Main_Model` object

```
class SubForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sub_Model

def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = SubForm(request.POST, prefix='no1')
        form2 = SubForm(request.POST, prefix='no2')
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
           main_model = Main_Model(field1 = form1.save(),
                                   field2 = form2.save())
           main_model.save()
           #...
     else:
         form1 = SubForm(prefix = 'no1')
         form2 = SubForm(prefix = 'no2')
     return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form1': form1,
                                                   'form2': form2})
```

Comment: ahh yes, I was afraid I was going to have to do something like this, I just have a lot more stuff in my models since it is for a data collection for my university, I just didn't know if there was a nifty Django trick that I could use to do this. Helpful regardless, +1. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Aidan Ewen, do you know how I would include those two models in admin, but not as a drop down list, like inlines. I can't use inlines because of how the main model has two foreign keys to the subclass.

Comment: What's wrong with the way they're currently handled? I suggest you open a new question, with a bit more detail, explaining the behavior you want and the behavior you're getting.